# how to position a block in magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, layout

[image]

I want to add referral code block to move on the top, above Payment Method. How can I do it?

**Layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="creditamount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">My_Module/js/view/payment/customform</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just use `beforeMethods` for getting Referral code in above the payment method.

```
<item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="creditamount" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">My_Module/js/view/payment/customform</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
```

FULL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="creditamount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">My_Module/js/view/payment/customform</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: please let me know if you have query

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried this code,  but it's  not working also deployed static contents after changing code.

Comment: any error came?

Comment: No error, page is displaying as before

Comment: @jassi Glad to know you have useful.